# Changing Picklist to Multipicklist and using in formula field

Tags: formula-field, configuration, multi-select

I have changed the picklist fields to multiselect picklist and trying to use this in the formula filed getting below error. kindly some one help.

Field changed as
Mand_A__c(Picklist) ------> Changed to  Mand_A__c (Multiselect)

Formula :-

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Rist_A__C))), TEXT(Risk_ov__c), TEXT(Mand_A__c))
```

Error i am getting.

```
rror: Field Mand_A__c is a multi-select picklist field. Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain function
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try googling the error message? One of the main search results will be this article in salesforce help:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&type=5

So, depending on your logic, you will have to change the formula to something using CONTAINS() or INCLUDES().

Comment: Is there any way or example available

Comment: yes on that page there's a link that will take you to the explanations per function.

"For more details about the functions, see Formula and Operator Functions."
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&language=en_US&type=5